# Oracle Relational Division Query

Tags: sql, oracle, relational-division

I am trying to write a Relational Division query (I am required to use Relational Division for this) 
Given the following tables:

Guest:

```
   GID      PHNUM FNAME           LNAME                CCNUM RESDATE                                                                                                                                                         
  1654 3132565356 Tyrone          Biggums               8420 2016-11-04                                                                           
  1743 2484352574 Noah            Colon                 3345 2016-11-03                                                                           
  1501 2487615478 Brennan         Luttrell              6426 2016-11-05
```

Room:

```
ROOMNUM ROOMTYPE          GID                                                                                                                      

   101 Suite            1654                                                                                                                      
   103 Suite                                                                                                                                      
   105 Suite            1743                                                                                                                      
   107 Suite                                                                                                                                      
   108 Double           1501                                                                                                                      
   115 Double           1654                                                                                                                      
   117 Double                                                                                                                                     
   130 Single           1501                                                                                                                      
   135 Single           1501
```

Employee:

```
SSN       SUPERSSN  FNAME           LNAME                PHNUM       WAGE                                                                                                                      
123456789           Jim             Lahey           2464572367         40                                                               
532674246 123456789 Geno            Bianco          2463601456         15                                                             
837264268 123456789 Randy           Bobandy         2463603678         10                                                                
738643653 837264268 Corey           Trevor          2464326734          7                                                                 
648753674 837264268 Joshua          Trussler        2464327535          8
```

Maintains:

```
EMPLOYEES    ROOMNUM                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
648753674        101                                                                                                                                  
648753674        115                                                                                                                                  
738643653        101                                                                                                                                  
738643653        105                                                                                                                                  
738643653        108                                                                                                                                  
738643653        130                                                                                                                                  
738643653        135                                                                                                                                  
837264268        107
```

I am trying to write a query that would use relational division to select every employee who cleans every room reserved by a guest whose GID = 1654

The query I have written is as follows:

```
SELECT E.ssn, E.lname, E.fname
FROM employee E
WHERE NOT EXISTS((SELECT G.gid
                  FROM guest G
                  WHERE G.gid = 1654)
                  MINUS
                  (SELECT G.gid
                   FROM maintains M, room R, guest G
                   WHERE G.gid = R.gid
                   AND R.roomnum = M.roomnum
                   AND E.ssn = M.employeessn
                   AND G.gid = 1654));
```

However, in it's current form it returns the following, which is incorrect:

```
SSN       LNAME           FNAME                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
738643653 Trevor          Corey                                                                                                                       
648753674 Trussler        Joshua
```

Any and all help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: "[Divided We Stand: The SQL of Relational Division](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)" by Joe Celko is a standard article about relational division.

Comment: What was your justification for that query? What division do you think it represents?

Answer (score 0):

You could count all rooms and rooms maintained by employee and take only rows with equal values:

```
select distinct ssn, fname, lname
  from (select e.ssn, e.fname, e.lname, 
               count(distinct r.roomnum) over () cnt_room, 
               count(1) over (partition by e.ssn) cnt_ssn
          from room r
          join maintains m on m.roomnum = r.roomnum
          join employee e  on e.ssn = m.employeessn
          where gid = 1654)
  where cnt_room = cnt_ssn
```

**<sup>[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/83b2cd/225)</sup>**

Result:

```
       SSN FNAME  LNAME
---------- ------ --------
 648753674 Joshua Trussler
```